# Loading groovy class with dependencies

Tags: java, groovy

Say I wanted to use `GroovyClassLoader` to load a class that uses several other classes

```
test1.groovy  
|  
|_test2.groovy
|            |
|            test3.groovy
|
test4.groovy
```

Other than loading them in order `test4->test3->test2->test1`. Could I just load `test1` and have all of its dependencies loaded with it?

Comment: Is this from Java?  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, this is from java. If you don't load them in order, you will get a `MultipleCompilationErrorsException`.

Comment: Can you give a simple example I can test?

Comment: `GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader();  
loader.loadClass("test1");  
loader.close();` assuming you used the little graph above, it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `File1.groovy` like:

```
import File2

new File2().sayHi( 'tim' )
```

And `File2.groovy` like:

```
class File2 {
    def sayHi( name ) {
        println "Hi $name"
    }
}
```

And `Test.java` like:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader ;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject ;

public class Test {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader() ;
        GroovyObject o = (GroovyObject)loader.loadClass( "File1" ).newInstance() ;
        o.invokeMethod( "run", new Object[] {} ) ;
        loader.close() ;
    }
}
```

I can compile it with:

```
javac -cp groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:. Test.java
```

And when I do:

```
java -cp groovy-all-2.2.1.jar:. Test
```

It prints:

```
Hi tim
```

How is my example different to what you have, and can you add the difference in to your question?

Comment: Other than using `loader.addClasspath("test")` yours is pretty much the same.

Comment: I figured it out and it made me feel rather dumb. My Test2 was in test2.groovy instead of Test2.groovy.